# What is the set of homomorphisms $\hom_\text{Ring} (\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z}_{m})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

(For $A,B$ rings and $R$-modules, denote
$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$
$\Hom_\text{Ring}(A,B)$ the ring of ring homomorphisms $A \to B$, contrasted with $\Hom_R(A,B)$ which is the R-module of $R$-module homomorphisms.)

> Find $\Hom_\text{Ring} (\mathbb{Z}_n, \mathbb{Z}_m)$.

It's obvious that $\Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z}_{m}) = \mathbb{Z}_{(n,m)}$ and I found that if $\phi \in \Hom_\text{Ring}(\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z}_{m})$ (as ring)  $\iff \phi(1)=\phi(1)^2, \phi \in {\rm Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z}_{m})$.

But it gives no benefit to me in general case.

Comment: So i need to find all idempotents $a$ with additional condition:$ord(a) | n$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I believe it is: what is $\mathrm{Hom}_{Ring}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$?